# Adding property values to a maven archetype

Tags: java, xml, maven, archetypes

Is it possible to add property values to a maven archetype so that these are requested on generation from a repository?

I'm trying to create an archetype from a project that contains strings such as ${mainUrl} in a config.xml file.

Im trying to set this up from the pom before i generate it. However the result is that that ${mainUrl} never changes. And attempts to set it via a properties file never succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , found a solution.

I had to generate the archetype from my project with the required property added like this to the pom.xml

```
<properties>
<mainUrl>main-url</mainUrl>
</properties>
```

After generation using "mvn archetype:create-from-project"

I added the xml below to archetype-metadata.xml

```
<requiredProperties>
<requiredProperty key="mainUrl"/>
</requiredProperties>
```

And to archetype.properties added
"mainUrl=test"

Then ran "mvn clean install" on the archetype.

Now when i generate the archetype with "mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local"

It also prompts me to enter "mainUrl" and changes instances of ${mainUrl} to the url entered.